# Nested JSON data will cause crash using NS Dictionary (in Swift)

Tags: ios, json, xcode, nsdictionary, swift

I'm trying to fetch movie information in JSON format using JSONSerialization in Swift and save it as an NSDictionary. However, calling the Rotten Tomatoes API (in which information is nested) will cause my Playground to crash (without giving me any useful errors).

I know the code is somewhat valid, since calling other APIs which don't nest their data works (but don't fulfill my need).

Here's the code:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSDictionary {
    var url = NSURL(string: urlToRequest)

    var error: NSError?
    let jsonData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url , options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)

    let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    return jsonDict
}
let movieData: NSDictionary = getJSON(apiURL)
```

here's a sample from the Rotten Tomatoes API JSON (shortened for illustration purposes, this is the actual JSON file, not the output from my code)

```
{
    "id": 770672122,
    "title": "Toy Story 3",
    "year": 2010,
    "genres": ["Animation", "Kids & Family", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "Comedy"],
    "release_dates": {
        "theater": "2010-06-18",
        "dvd": "2010-11-02"
    },
    "ratings": {
        "critics_rating": "Certified Fresh",
        "critics_score": 99,
        "audience_rating": "Upright",
        "audience_score": 89
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possibly wrapped in an array `[]`? Please provide a working URL to "Rotten Tomatoes".

Comment: @Zaph I can't give you a URL as it contains my unique API Key, but if you go here, you'll see sample outputs from different kinds of requests http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs - how you see them there is exactly how they show up when I request them (according to my browser, at least, since I can't do it on Xcode)

Comment: Is the code you posted from an `NSLog()` from your app of a copy/paste from the Rotten Tomatoes site?

Comment: @Zaph Copied from the site - as soon as I try to input a rotten tomatoes URL in the code above, it crashes, so can't get the log. Note that inputting the URL on my browser returns the exact same thing (minus the formatting) as what the RT website shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me in a Swift iOS app (crashes Xcode when run in a playground:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSDictionary {
    var url = NSURL(string: urlToRequest)

    var error: NSError?
    let jsonData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url , options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)
    let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    return jsonDict
}
let apiURL = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122.json?apikey=9p4xwzpgt8xp2vahnyx2sc6g"
let movieData: NSDictionary = getJSON(apiURL)
println(movieData)
```

It looks like the crash you are getting is a playground error.

Note, Swift is basically guaranteed to have bugs, it is an early Beta.

Also explicitly state they the JSON is example code, not fro running your code.

Comment: I've created a temporary API key for you to see - here's a sample URL which works http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122.json?apikey=9p4xwzpgt8xp2vahnyx2sc6g
I tried running Charles, and it reported successful access, so I think the server is fine - let me know what you think the problem could be. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Looking at my Playground, it seems to run the fetch and jsonData parts fine, and crashes as it tries to process the jsonDict part - hence why I think it is a JSON error

Comment: thanks a lot! I guess I shouldn't put too much trust into playground yet - and I'll edit the question to be clearer

Comment: Right now the playground seems to have multiple problems with displaying nested NSDictionary and NSArray.  Basically speaking, no matter what you input it shouldn't crash :)